# Использование компонентов Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, компоненты

У меня есть компонент(в этом случае не важно какой, важна суть), в котором что-то записано в `template`, все по дефолту.

В главной программе (new Vue) так же есть `template`, где вызывается компонент

```
template: `<название компонента></название компонента>`
```

И вот как раз появился вопрос по поводу многократного вызова этого компонента.
Например этот компонент, что нужно использовать - это строка в таблице, но заранее не известно сколько будет строчек, так как их количество вводит пользователь.

Такая запись не работает и выдает ошибку, что нельзя создавать мультикомпоненты в `template`, используя `v-for`, что-то в этом роде:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#matrix',
  data: {
    rows: 0
  },
  template: '<testComponent v-for="c in ${this.rows}"></testComponent>',
  methods: {
    inputRows(event) {
      this.rows = event.target.value
    },
  }
})
```

---

Можно как-то вызывать template столько раз, сколько нужно или же вызывать компонент столько раз, сколько нужно? Как правильно сделать цикл в данном случае? Где его применить?

Comment: Эм.. А что с `v-for`?

Comment: Об этом и спрашиваю, как правильно его записать?  `new Vue({
         el: '#matrix',
         data: {
            rows: 0
         },
         template: '<testComponent v-for="c in ${this.rows}"></testComponent>',
         methods: {
            inputRows(event) {
               this.rows = event.target.value
            },
         }
      })`

Comment: Такая запись не работает и выдает ошибку, что нельзя создавать мультикомпоненты в template, используя  v-for, что-то в этом роде

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> выдает ошибку, что нельзя создавать мультикомпоненты в template, используя v-for, что-то в этом роде

Нельзя использовать директиву `v-for` ***на корневом элементе*** шаблона.
А вообще в `template` - использовать можно.

```js
Vue.component('test-component', {
  template: '<div></div>'
}); 

new Vue({
  el: '#matrix', 
  data: {
    rows: 0
  }, 
  template: `
    <div>
      <input v-model.lazy.number="rows" type="range" min="0" max="50" value="0"> {{ rows }}
      <test-component v-for="c in rows"></test-component>
    </div>
  `
});
```

```html
<div id="matrix"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Если же надо отрисовать *несколько* компонентов через `v-for`, то их следует обернуть в HTML-элемент или `<template>`. Второе - предпочтительнее (документация: [v-for и тег template](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3-template)).

Comment: А можете сказать, пожалуйста, зачем тут знак плюса перед `rows`?

Comment: @Colibri, для преобразования строкового значения в числовое. Вместо этого можно использовать `v-model.number`. Модификатор `.number` даже лучше, кстати... обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию